# This App is blocked error while extracting lifetime refresh token using OAuth Playground to supply to Azure Google Adwords linked service connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-ads-api, oauth2-playground

While authorizing my Google Ads Account using OAuth Playground to retrieve a lifetime refresh token which could used to further create access tokens, the authorization is throwing `This app is blocked` security error. I think this is because the GCP OAuth consent screen is not verified. But how do I verify my OAuth consent screen when I don't have an App domain name, since I'm using this as a one time activity to retrieve my refresh token using OAuth Playground?

Comment: You must have a domain name you control/own that is properly configured.

Comment: @JohnHanley but since I use OAuth Playground to retrieve a lifetime refresh token and I’m using azure ADF to extract data I don’t have to set up an App. Can we provide our organisation’s website and it’s privacy policy ? We are doing something very similar to https://eastern-analytics.us/blog/how-to-connect-azure-data-factory-adf-to-google-bigquery?hs_amp=true

Comment: The OAuth Playground is for **testing** and **learning**. You must set up an OAuth Client with your own domain. Otherwise, you will continue to get blocked.

Comment: Does that mean I can generate the refresh token with OAuth Playground n then create web app to fetch the data using client creds and refresh token  ? Does that mean gcp does not support azure adf copy activity data extraction for google services  ?

Comment: No, it does not. You must create your own OAuth Client in the Google Cloud project. forget about using OAuth Playground and do things correctly. Otherwise, you will only have problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley Google Adwords suggest we can use OAuth Playground to manually generate the token https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/playground

Comment: Go ahead and continue down that path. You will have problems and then you will have to start over and do it correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley Agree with you on this. Nothing has been mentioned as to how to configure the OAuth Screen if we manually create the refresh token using OAuth Playground. Thank you for your recommendations